# Angular HttpClient is not working in real device

Tags: asp.net, angular, ionic4

Net webservices to get the data from the Database. when i am testing that webservice using angular httpclientmodule in the browser i am getting the data. But when i am building the Ionic App and testing in real device unable to get the Data.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
let params = new HttpParams();
this.http.get('URL',{headers: headers,params:params,responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((res)=>{

});
```

Comment: What error do you get in the browser's development console?

Comment: I think you should show more of your code, because actualy it look like you do not do it well, so it's logical that it don't work

Comment: Actually i am getting the data in the browser but unable to get the data in the real device.

Comment: [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public int Login(string username, string password)
    {
    }

Comment: my guess would be a CORS issue

Comment: I enabled the cors also in the server then also i am getting the issue